# How to change just one parameter using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to update my global state using Redux, but I try to update just one paramter of five, not all.

My store code looks like:

```
const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    thisUser: {}
}

export function usersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'users/loggedIn':
            return { ...state, loggedIn: action.payload }
        case 'users/addUser':
            return { ...state, thisUser: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I tried to write a new case like, but doesn't work:

```
case 'users/setActivated':
            return { ...state, thisUser.activated: action.payload }
```

VS Code doesn't let me write that ".activated"

My dispatch look like:

```
dispatch({ type: 'users/setActivated', payload: 1 })
```

What is  wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand why you did this, it seemed logical to you, but it will not work.

```
 const state = {
    ...state,
    [thisUser.activated]: action.payload
  };
```

So your goal is to update the state to be like this:

```
{
    loggedIn: true,
    thisUser: {
      //other properties ,
      activated: 1,
    }
  }
```

Firstly, this is the output of what you did:

```
{
    loggedIn: true,
    thisUser: {
      //other properties ,
      activated: 0,
    },
    activated: 1,
  };
```

Secondly, JavaScript doesn't accept this `thisUser.activated` as a key.

The solution:

```
 {
    ...state,
    thisUser: { 
      ...state.thisUser, 
      activated: action.payload
    },
  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Now I know what was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your syntax is wrong, that's what. :)

```
case 'users/setActivated':
    return { ...state, thisUser: {...state.thisUser, activated: action.payload} }
```

is what you need to shallow-merge `state` with a shallow-merged nested object.

Note that it quickly gets very old to dig into objects like that, and you might want to look at e.g. [`immer`](https://github.com/immerjs/immer).